# Reduce strings in python to a specific point

Tags: python, string, path

I have strings in my python application that look this way:

```
test1/test2/foo/
```

Everytime I get such a string, I want to reduce it, beginning from the tail and reduced until the fist "/" is reached.

```
test1/test2/
```

More examples:

```
foo/foo/foo/foo/foo/  => foo/foo/foo/foo/
test/test/            => test/
how/to/implement/this => how/to/implement/
```

How can I implement this in python?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 newString = oldString[:oldString[:-1].rfind('/')]
 # strip out trailing slash    ----^       ^---- find last remaining slash
```

Comment: Alternatively you can use `.rfind('/', 0, -2)`.

Comment: this is really is one of the poorest answers.

Comment: I agree with SilentGhost, this really is one of the worst alternatives. The os.path based answers are much better.

Comment: Well, I had no idea it was for paths!

Comment: This solution is best for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like the [`os.path.dirname`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.dirname) function might be what you're looking for. You may need to call it more than once:

```
>>> import os.path
>>> os.path.dirname("test1/test2/")
'test1/test2'
>>> os.path.dirname("test1/test2")
'test1'
```

Comment: `dirname` is useful in general, but in this case the user wants `test2` to be removed on both cases.

Answer (score 5):

[`str.rsplit()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit) with the `maxsplit` argument. Or if this is a path, look in `os.path` or `urlparse`.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import os
>>> path="how/to/implement/this"
>>> os.path.split(path)
('how/to/implement', 'this')
>>> os.path.split(path)[0]
'how/to/implement'
```

Comment: This works only for this specific example (string). But it is not a generic solution.

Comment: what are the string examples that breaks when this method is used?

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> os.path.split('how/to/implement/this'.rstrip('/'))
('how/to/implement', 'this')
>>> os.path.split('how/to/implement/this/'.rstrip('/'))
('how/to/implement', 'this')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'/'.join(s.split('/')[:-1]+[''])
```

Comment: There are approximately half a dozen techniques that are better than this.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean "/" as in path separator, the function you want is:

```
os.path.dirname(your_argument)
```

If not, then you want:

```
def your_function(your_argument):
    result= your_argument.rstrip("/").rpartition("/")[0]
    if result:
        return result + "/"
    return result
```

Please specify what should be the result when "test/" is used as an argument: should it be "/" or ""? I assumed the second in my code above.